# Ransack search all record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I restart the server after bundlen install

My environment

ruby 2.1.5, rails 4.0.13, ransack 1.6.3

results with the console

```
User.first
=> #<User id: 1, email: "email@mail.com">

User.ransack({"email"=>"email@mail.com"}).result.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\""

User.search({"email"=>"email@mail.com"}).result.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\""

User.where({"email"=>"email@mail.com"}).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"email\" = 'email@mail.com'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it wrongly. Your *Ransack* query  should be :

```
User.ransack(email_eq: "email@mail.com").result
```

Read the [eq (equals)](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching#eq-equals) documentation.